# Insert Value from Join Result SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Let's say I have 2 tables, recently added new column in tbl_review called city and wishing for it to be filled from other table (tbl_bus)

```
tbl_review (uid,bid,rate,city)

tbl_bus (bid,city,lat,long)
```

normally I would join

```
select A.city B.uid from tbl_bus A inner join tbl_review B on A.bid=B.bid
```

Now i want to insert city value based on data in tbl_bus, is it possible?

Thanks

Comment: If value of city in both the table are same. Then i don't think so city column in both the table is required.

Comment: `update tbl_bus A
 inner join tbl_review B on A.bid=B.bid
   set A.city=B.city`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your records are already in the table, you don't want to `INSERT`, you want to `UPDATE`.

```
UPDATE tbl_review a
LEFT JOIN tbl_bus b
    ON a.bid = b.bid
SET a.city = COALESCE(b.city, 'NA')
```

The `LEFT JOIN` could reveal that some records in `tbl_review` do not have matching cities in `tbl_bus`.  In this case, I chose to use the text `NA` as a placeholder.  If you don't mind nulls, then you can remove `COALESCE`.

However, from a design point of view, it might be undesirable to have the same `city` information stored across two tables, as @BhavinSolanki mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try following query:

```
Update tbl_review,tbl_bus
set tbl_review.city=tbl_bus.city 
WHERE tbl_review.uid = tbl_bus.bid;
```

Answer (score 0):

Update tbl_review,tbl_bus
set tbl_review.city=tbl_bus.city 
WHERE tbl_bus.uid = tbl_review.bid;